# How do i change my merge algorithm to accept different arguments in c++?

Tags: c++, merge

The original code i wrote uses these arguments:

int m = size of sorted list 1

int n = size of sorted list 2

int A[] = sorted list 1

int B[] = sorted list 2

int C[] = merged list of 1 and 2

I was asked to add this code to an existing file that uses these different arguments:

IntVectorIt start1

IntVectorIt end1

IntVectorIt start2

IntVectorIt end2

IntVectorIt start3

These variables are defined here (n is size of first sorted array, m is size of second sorted array):

```
typedef vector<int> IntVector;

typedef IntVector::iterator IntVectorIt;

IntVector Vector1(n);
IntVectorIt start1,end1,it1;
start1 = Vector1.begin();
end1 = Vector1.end();

IntVector Vector2(m);
IntVectorIt start2,end2,it2;
start2 = Vector2.begin();
end2 = Vector2.end();

IntVector Vector3(n+m);
IntVectorIt start3,end3,it3;
start3 = Vector3.begin();
end3 = Vector3.end();

//--The variables for my version of merge
IntVector MyVector(n+m);
IntVectorIt mystart,myend,myit;
mystart = MyVector.begin();
myend = MyVector.end();
```

My merge code:

```
void mymerge(int m, int n, int A[], int B[], int C[])
{
  int i, j, k = 0;

  while (i < m && j < n)
  {
        if (A[i] <= B[j])
        {
              C[k] = A[i];
              i++;
        }

        else
        {
              C[k] = B[j];
              j++;
        }

        k++;
  }

  if (i < m)
  {
        for (int p = i; p < m; p++)
        {
              C[k] = A[p];
              k++;
        }
  } 

  else
  {
        for (int p = j; p < n; p++)
        {
              C[k] = B[p];
              k++;
        }

  }

}
```

If anyone could help me figure out how i could take those iterators as arguments, it would help me out a ton.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: yeah for a cs class at NEU... is it not allowed here?

Comment: @user177215: homework is allowed, but it should be tagged as homework. Some people feel strongly about it, others not, but in general you'll get more hints and clues for "homework" questions, rather than people posting code. I do wonder, actually, how long before someone gets wrongly accused by anti-plagiarism software, because their submitted code closely resembles *their own first attempt*, which they posted on SO, and the software thinks they copied...

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I'll keep that in mind for future homework posts. It just bothers me that I didn't read the whole assignment before I made my own version of merge. All I'm asking for are hints and clues.  Although sections of code never hurt :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it sounds like homework, I won't write the whole solution. However, here are some suggestions on migrating `mymerge`:

Change the signature to

```
void mymerge(
    IntVectorIt aStart,
    IntVectorIt aEnd,
    IntVectorIt bStart, 
    IntVectorIt bEnd,
    IntVectorIt cStart, 
    IntVectorIt cEnd
    );
```

Change the running indices to iterators, e.g.

```
IntVectorIt i = aStart;
```

Change the loop stopping condition to use iterators, e.g.

```
i != aEnd
```

Comment: Or, if you think you can get away with it, just call your existing function from the version with the correct signature. `vector` stores its contents contiguously, just like an array. So you can just pass `aEnd - aStart` for `m`, `&*aStart` for `A` (if m != 0), and so on. *But* that only works because you've been asked to do it for vector, so although it's easy right now, you probably won't be well positioned for the next assignment...

Comment: thank you to both of you... i just finished with this help :D